# Java - Missing artifact com.sun:tools:jar:0 (POM.xml)

Tags: java, pom

Estou tomando esse erro no meu POM.xml. 
Alguém saberia me dizer o que pode ser?

[image: Missing artifact com.sun:tools:jar:0]

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
```

**Markers**

> The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library
>   'C:\Users\vinicius.ribeiro.m2\repository\com\sun\tools\0\tools-0.jar'    VR      Build
>   path  Build Path Problem The project cannot be built until build path
>   errors are resolved   VR      Unknown Java Problem Missing artifact
>   com.sun:tools:jar:0   pom.xml /VR line 1  Maven Dependency Problem

**POM**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <!--PROJECT_AND_VERSION-->
  <groupId>POC</groupId>
  <artifactId>VR</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-ProveOfConceptBranch</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <!--RELATED_INFO-->
  <name>VR</name>
  <url>http://qa360.com.br/</url>

  <!--BUILD_INFO-->
  <build>
       <plugins>
             <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <!--MAVEN'S VERSION-->
                    <version>3.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                           <!--JAVA'S_VERSION-->
                           <source>1.8</source>
                           <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
             </plugin>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                        -Dcucumber.options="--plugin ru.yandex.qatools.allure.cucumberjvm.AllureReporter"
                    </argLine>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <!--Needed only to show reports locally. Run jetty:run and
            open localhost:8080 to show the report-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.2.10.v20150310</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webAppSourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site/allure-maven-plugin</webAppSourceDirectory>
                    <stopKey>stop</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>1234</stopPort>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <cucumber.version>1.2.0</cucumber.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>

  <!--JUnit-->
      <dependency>
             <groupId>junit</groupId>
             <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
             <version>4.11</version>
             <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

    <!-- SELENIUM -->
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

    <!-- CUCUMBER -->
       <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
             <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
             <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
             <version>1.2.5</version>
             <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>

    <!-- GHERKIN PLUGIN -->
       <dependency>
             <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
             <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
             <version>2.12.2</version>
             <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>

     <!-- MOCKITO PLUGIN -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>  

     <!-- COBERTURA PLUGIN -->  
       <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.cobertura</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>

     <!-- ALLURE PLUGIN -->
       <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-cucumber-jvm-adaptor</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
       </dependency>

     <!-- SLF4J PLUGIN 
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency> -->

  </dependencies>

  <!--PROJECT_DESCRIPTION-->
  <description>Prove of concecpt which it's main purpose is to automate: &quot;Simule e Compre&quot; functionality available on 'https://www.vr.com.br/portal/portal-vr/area-publica/simule-e-compre/&quot;.

  Pre requirements are: 
 - Must be constructed with Selenium;
 - Must be constructed with BDD and Cucumber; 
 - Must have DDT support with Excel; 
 - Must have cross-browsing support using Selenium Grid;

This software was made by QA360 ALL RIGHTS RESERVED.</description>


  <organization>
    <name>VR Benefícios</name>
    <url>https://www.vr.com.br/</url>
  </organization>
</project>
```

**Variáveis**

**CLASSPATH** = %JAVA_HOME%\lib;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\dt.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\htmlconverter.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\rt.jar;

**JAVA_HOME** = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_71

Comment: Como estão suas dependências? E seus plugins?

Comment: Poderia postar seu "pom.xml", no lugar da imagem seria mais fácil oferecer uma solução.

Comment: O erro é indicado na primeira linha, mas não necessariamente ele mora de fato na primeira linha. Pode ser algo lá na linha 800

Comment: Adicionei o POM e as Dependências.

Answer (score 0):

Tente um destes três caminhos:

1) No Eclipse, vá em Windows -> settings -> Java -> installed JREs -> selecione JDK e clique Edit -> Add External JARs e adicione tools.jar (fica na pasta `lib` dentro da sua instalação do jdk na sua máquina).

2) No arquivo eclipse.ini, ANTES da linha -vmargs, adicione o parâmetro `-vm` e, abaixo dele, o path da pasta bin do seu jdk. Por exemplo:

```
-vm 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_35\bin
```

3) No Eclipse, abra o seu arquivo pom.xml clicando nele com o botão direito e escolhendo Open With > Maven POM Editor. Lá, você terá uma tab chamada Dependency Hierarchy. Ela tem uma caixinha de busca, onde você digita tools (a ideia é saber se alguma lib do seu projeto tem dependência  da lib tools.jar). Se existir, você deverá criar uma exclusão para ela no pom. Para uma screenshot tanto da tab quanto da exclusão no pom.xml, clique [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32871694/4319922).

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver. O problema estava no build do maven ao criar as pastas no .m2. Criei as pastas na mão e dei uma update project. Após isso voltou tudo ao normal.

Obg, pessoal.